# Constructing objects in c++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, static

So, I'm coming from Java, learning c++. I want to implement a program that can be called like this, provided by a test file (boots):

```
auto subject = anagram::anagram("diaper");
auto matches = subject.matches({"hello", "world", "zombies","pants"});
vector<string> expected;
BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(expected.begin(), expected.end(), matches.begin(), matches.end());
```

Do I get it right, that `anagram::anagram(...)` is a constructor, constructing an Object that provides the method `matches(...)`? Because in my Implementation (cf. below) I get an error saying something (not in english) like "constructor can not be called directly". I think there is something I do not understand about constructors in c++.

```
// this is part of my implementation of anagram.h
class anagram{

public:
    anagram(const string a);
    vector<string> matches(vector<string> &list);

private:
    string a;
    bool isAnagram(string s);    
};
```

The only other thing I know is that `anagram::anagram(...)` could be a static method, with a return value that is similat to `this`, but that wouldn't make sense to me. So it would be nice if someone could explain this :)

Comment: `auto subject = anagram::anagram("diaper");` isn't a valid constructor call.

Comment: It might be a factory function inside namespace.

Comment: Typo; Constructors are "called" like `ClassName(stuff)` or `ClassName{stuff}`.  You do not qualify the call like `CalssName::ClassName(stuff)

Comment: ok I understand it's not a constructor, but nor is it a typo (I'm pretty sure) since it is a testfile provided by an online code exercise website. Can you elaborate on that factory function?

Comment: Jean-Baptiste Yunès uses a factory function, the one you accepted only wraps the class in a namespace of its own name, which ends up doing the same as in my answer, plus `anagram::` behind.

Comment: @asu you are right, I myself would have written that code differently, but since its a test, I need to stick with what I am given and provide that useless namespace

Comment: oh, I didn't understand you couldn't modify the test case. Then the answer your accepted is likely the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it can work with syntax you have shown is if class `anagram` is placed in similary named namespace:

```
#include <string>
namespace anagram 
{
class anagram
{
  public:
    anagram(std::string s) {}
};
}

int main() 
{
    auto subject = anagram::anagram("diaper");
}
```

http://ideone.com/1OVhIz

Comment: this is irrelevant because he assumed `anagram`'s constructor could be called as any other static method.

Comment: Does it even make sense to do something like this?

Comment: It's just providing you the same syntax as the one you mentioned, but it is uselessly verbose, imo. Without the namespace you'd just end up doing `anagram("thing")` and not `anagram::anagram("thing")`... I don't think it is better. edit: especially considering `auto thing = anagram::anagram("foo");` is even longer than just `anagram::anagram thing{"foo"};`

Comment: @suffi well, it does make sense to put your classes/functions out of global namespace to avoid name clashes with code of people who don't. And if your project involves anagrams, it might be logical to have a namespace with class `anagram`, helper function `is_anagram`, and other stuff which is related to art of anagram handling. Name _anagram_ is first which comes to mind when thinking about how to call such namespace. So incidentally such naming might have sense. What surely doesn't make sense is placing each class in unique namespace with same name.

Answer (score 2):

Because you come from java you are used to see something similiar like this:

```
 someobject T = new someObject(argument);
```

---

in C++ you construct a class in a different way:

```
 someObject T(argument);
```

and tada you created an Object with name T in c++. an other way is to create a pointer to an object:

```
someObject *T = new someObject(argument);
```

which is more similar to java but now you have to delete that pointer manually. It is always better to create objects on the stack rather the heap. it avoids memory leaks.

---

To answer you question: You got it wrong. You call Constructors like i showed you earlier. you are right about how to call a static memberfunction but this does not apply for the Ctor because it can never be static nor virtual.

Comment: Using the heap in a situation where you could use the stack *can* sometimes have benefits. I once had a situation where I had a large array allocated on the stack that was performing much worse than a `std::vector` (which uses the heap internally); likely for cache reasons. But in general cases, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: So it actually is a static function? But `matches` is still  an object of class angram, right?

Comment: Yes, but for what it's worth specifying the type of `matches` would make the code likely more clear and not that much longer. It is useful when you have long names like when you handle iterators, tuples, etc.

Comment: @suffi No it is not a static function!!!!! The Ctor cannot be static!!!!

Comment: Uh, I wouldn't call a constructor a static function because this is quite ambiguous. Doing `someObject(argument)` will effectively allocate and construct the `someObject` object. You may also be interested by [object lifetimes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)

Comment: @exofde there is a confusion: My implementation is assuming the test wants to call a constructor, where it doesn't. So i need to rewrite my class, erase the constructor and implement a static factory function instead, i think

Comment: I don't get it... You asked to call for the constructor of anagram, right? So why would you need a factory?

Answer (score 2):

If the call `anagram::anagram` must work `anagram` is a namespace inside it a function called `anagram` is defined to return an object onto which you can call a method `matches` :

```
namespace anagram {
  SomeType anagram(string n) { return SomeType(n); }
};
```

That also could be a class name `anagram` inside a namespace `anagram`.

That couldn't be a static method as no method except ctors can use the name of the class as identifier.

Comment: +1 this is it, but I think @revolver_ocelot was a little faster, even though I didn't understand what he was saying at first, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax would actually look a similar way as in Java (except for the `new`, of course) :

```
auto subject = Anagram("diaper");
```

But there's an easier way:

```
Anagram subject("diaper");
Anagram subject{"diaper"}; // C++11 and newer
```

Also do note that if `Anagram` has a default constructor, it will be constructed when you define it - It can't be `null` or something like in java, unless you are using `*` pointers.

```
Anagram subject;
```

You may also build a temporary `Anagram` object so you don't need to define the `subject` variable :

```
auto matches = Anagram{"diaper"}.matches({"hello", "world", "zombies","pants"});
```

If you want to use dynamic allocation, you could use `new`, but there isn't any GC to delete the value when you don't need anymore...!

```
Anagram* subject = new Anagram("diaper");
// ... do some stuff with subject...
delete subject; // Destroy the dynamically allocated subject and deallocate it
```

If you ever want to use dynamic memory allocation, I would recommend you to use smart pointers which you can find on this [cpprefrence page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). They have many advantages over manual memory allocation.